# Issues with converting project to angularJS on eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tern

I am trying to get one of my angularJS project to work on eclipse. I have downloaded the angularJS plugins for eclipse, Started a Dynamic Web Project, and copied all my files into that folder. Now when I right click on the project and got to: Configure -> Convert to AngularJS Project, I get the Following error:

"Converting to angular project has encountered a problem..". Apparently, an internal error an whe I click details the it shows a problem with- tern/server/TernPlugin.angular1

And now every time I try to access any file from that project through the workspace this error jumps up:
'Synchronizing script resources with Tern server...' has encountered a problem

So basically I cannot convert my project to AngularJS. Anyone ever has similar issues?

Comment: Which version of AngularJS Eclipse have you installed? 1.1.0 or 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT? Have you a more detailled error in teh Error log view? Otherwise please share your project like github.

Comment: @Angelo I installed 1.2.0 SNAPSHOT. I cannot really share my project on github, but I can say that it happened with whatever project i started. Even just starting an empty web project and trying to convert to Angular. Unfortunately, there are no more details for that error.

Comment: Please reinstall AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0 SNAPSHOT. The update site was wrong because it missed websocket API and 1.2.0 SNAPSHOT uses now WebSocket.I suggest you too that you use Eclipse JEE Mars. Hope the new update ste will fix your problem.

Comment: Ok @Angelo, will do. Also, I am using your tutorial to add all the plugins to Eclipse. Is that tutorial updated?

Comment: The *-SNAPSHOT version is not a stable version so you can have some trouble like you had had. I have fixed the problem, hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok so it did fixed the first problem, thank you. Now the only problem is that even after adding all the plugins and configuring my project as AngularJS, I still get the source line - angular.min.js underlined in red, so I still needed to download angular manually and add it to my project workspace, Then it worked. But this is odd, since I thought that adding the plugins is supposed to be an alternative to actually downloading angular and adding it to my workspace.

Comment: To avoid having this problem, you can exclude angular.min.js with JSDT Install Path.